# Parar retorno do banco de dados - Mysql/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um problema para finalizar um projeto, preciso retornar os registros de uma tabela do banco de dados, porém, em alguns registros, tem um dado armazenado de forma diferente, então preciso parar a execução. Não consegui encontrar a solução até agora.

O que preciso, é: Apresentar como resultado, quantos registros estão com a coluna status `0`, limitando a no máximo `6` registros, caso tenham outros registros após 2 registros com status `0`, pare a execução.

Exemplo:

`Tabela: 11_07_2017_sala1`

`id   |   matricula_aluno    |   entrada    |   saida   |   status
1    |       0              |      6.5     |     7     |      0
2    |       0              |      7       |    7.5    |      0
3    |       2              |      7.5     |    8      |      1
4    |       2              |      8       |    8.5    |      1
5    |       2              |      8.5     |    9      |      1
6    |       0              |      9       |    9.5    |      0`

Quando fiz a Query com a cláusula `WHERE status = 0`, pulou os registros que estão com `status = 1`, mas continuou exibindo os resultados dos demais registros.

Adicionei `LIMIT 6`, porém, os registros continuavam retornando todos, com excessão daqueles em que o `status = 1`, limitando a 6 registros.

Qual seria a forma correta para essa aplicação?

Agradeço!

Comment: Consegue ser mais claro? Eu particularmente não consegui entender o que você quer fazer. Se possível, dê exemplos das duas situações: quando deve parar a execução e quando não deve.

Comment: O problema está no limit. pode postar sua querie? Eu já imagino o que seja!

Comment: Query com a cláusula WHERE e LIMIT: SELECT * FROM 11_07_2017_sala1 WHERE status = 0 LIMIT 6

Pode retornar mais registros se o status = 0

Não pode retornar caso o próximo registro o status = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua query com a clausula WHERE status = 0 só vai retornar valores 0 para status, portanto sem chances de verificar a situação `próximo registro o status = 1`

[**Break**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.break.php) é utilizado para controlar estruturas como while, do while, for e switch.

A função de break é forçar a saída de uma estrutura. Por exemplo, se tivermos uma estrutura de repetição que vai até um determinado número, mas que deve parar antes caso alguma condição seja satisfeita, neste caso usamos o break.

> No seu caso quando houver dois status `0` seguido de um status `não 0` OU `seis zeros seguidos`

```
//selecione sem where sem limit
SELECT * FROM 11_07_2017_sala1
$zeros=0;

..............................
..............................

    //condição para incrementar numero de status igual a 0
    if($status==0){
        $zeros=$zeros+1;

        //ação enquanto as condições não forem atendidas
        // EXEMPLO
        echo "<tr><td>".$id."</td><td>".$matricula_aluno."</td><td>".$entrada."</td><td>".$saida."</td><td>".$status."</td></tr>";

    }

    //aqui as condições para interromper a iteração
    if ((($zeros==2 && $status!=0))||($zeros==6)){
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Não atendeu a 100% da minha necessidade, mas deu uma luz no fim do túnel. Muito obrigado @leo-caracciolo

Comment: @HugoChristian o que estaria faltando para os 100%?

Comment: Foi apenas uma questão de operadores e estrutura mesmo, pois isso foi colocado dentro de um while, mas o ideal era um do while. Mas já está resolvido. Usei de forma diferente mas com a mesma base respondido por você:

`if ((($status >= 1 && $StatusReturn != 0)) || ($status == 6 )) {
                break;
            }` As demais alterações que fiz em seu código, foi para enquadrar na minha necessidade